# jQuery hover/click class

Tags: jquery, css, menuitem, addclass, jquery-hover

I'm creating a menue for a site.
I'm trying to accomplish a *hover* and *click* effect on links. I want the hover event on the elements *a* of the list to trigger a color animation and add the class 'active'. If the click and hover events are triggered I want to assign the same class to that element.
Problem is that the class must be removed once the element is not hovered and other element is clicked.
This is the code:

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="btHome">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="btAbout">NOSOTROS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="btGallery">GALERIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="btContact">CONTACTO</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.active{
    color:#0CF;
    background-image:url(../img/select.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right center;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#menu ul li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#0CF"}, 250); //I have the jQueryUI plugin
},function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#FFF"}, 100);
});

$("#menu ul li a").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', 150);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can continue chaining here, no need to have 2 separate selectors:

```
var allLinks = $("#menu ul li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#0CF"}, 250);
},function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('active')) // if it is not the active link
        $this.stop().animate({color: "#FFF"}, 100);
}).click(function() {
    allLinks.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', 150); // may need to adjust the timing here for better UX
});
```

Notice in the click handler remove any active class first.

Comment: Thanks. That solved some weird stuff going on. But when I stop hovering on the element the property 'color' of the 'active' class returns to white. That's because of the animation on the hover function. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#menu ul li a").hover(function() {
    $("#menu ul li a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#0CF"}, 250); //I have the jQueryUI plugin
},function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#FFF"}, 100);
});

$("#menu ul li a").click(function() {
    $("#menu ul li a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

It first removes the class `active` from all links it might have been attached to and then sets it to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest adding the hover and click effects through CSS3 using ':active' and ':hover'

As for some jQuery:

```
$('#menu li a').click(function() {
    $('#menu li a').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

And an example - http://jsfiddle.net/claycauley/AzXgX/

Comment: This would be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using css3 transitions:

http://jsfiddle.net/wrtyM/2/

Comment: I like this solution. No idea CSS3 was actually making color transitions. Brilliant.